# Next.js 13 app feature is not loading the CSS initialy, getting a glitch effect

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styles, next.js13

Hi i am using next js 13 app feature and its showing a glitch effect at the very first load of a page. The CSS file load after some time. Like when i try to get my login page it shows like this at first
[image]

But after some time (some mili seconds) it loads all the CSS and the page looks like this:

[image]

Please suggest a solution for this issue. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?